# Prevent modal background overlay to get darker on each new modal opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

How do I prevent modal's overlay to get darker for each new opened modal?

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rgyv9cn/) will makes things clear. You will notice the background overlay getting darker for each new modal.

I tried to *clear* the background of the subsequents modal windows adding a class with these properties:

```
background: none 
// and
background: transparent
// and
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) // reset bg
// and
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); // all clear and transparent bg
```

But none worked at all.

To be clear, I'm replacing [Kendo window](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window) by Bootstrap modal on my app and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy6puahy/) shows the exactly result I expect(which is working in my current app) but using Kendo.

Comment: Do you need the background or is it ok if it was removed totally?

Comment: I need it. It should work as a modal, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following style:

```
.modal + .modal-backdrop + .modal + .modal-backdrop {display:none}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3rgyv9cn/2)

or initiate the extra modals without a backdrop:

```
modal.modal({ show:true, backdrop: false });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3rgyv9cn/6)

The css version seems to be best though as it allows you to click opn the backdrop to close the modal where as the js version doesn't

**EDIT**

If you close the modal and open a new one, the above css fails.  This one should work instead

```
.modal + .modal-backdrop ~ .modal-backdrop {display:none}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3rgyv9cn/8/)

Comment: I like both methods. Thank you!

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown found a problem with the css selector, if you close a modal and opened another, it didn't work.  If you use the css see my edit

Comment: Nice, thanks. I ended up mixing js and css to get something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3rgyv9cn/9/)(add 5 windows and you will get what I mean).

Comment: If you want to keep your backgrounds whilst closing the modals you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/3rgyv9cn/12/

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in chrome:

```
.modal-open .modal-backdrop.in:nth-child(2) { opacity: .5 }
.modal-backdrop.in { opacity: 0 }
```

But generally I would suggest not opening a modal in a modal.  You'll also want to do something similar for the box-shadow.

http://jsfiddle.net/pjuv6uzx/

Comment: But I need. My app can have infinite modal opened at the same. BTW, your example makes the modal content a little opaque.

Comment: Thank you.. in fact I will use a mix of the javascript version proposed by @Pete and css, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3rgyv9cn/9/)(add at least 4 windows). Of course there is some errors but its just an example.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Laravel - vue project with bootstrap modals.
I have a modal whose content changes via vue's if statements.
Anyway, the modal background has no problems on dekstops or Android devices. However, on iOS the modal background flickers when something changes inside the modal, although it does not actually closes or reopens. The background overlay 'flickers' in that it gets darker (less opacity) and then goes back to the normal opacity state.
This seems to have fixed it in my case:

```
.modal-open .modal{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```

(so adding: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto; fixed it)